# XSLT: iterating over variable array to get sorted result not working. 

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

I am parsing itunes library xml file. The information in it is stored in following manner.
Tracks information are stored separately and playlist information are stored differently. A playlist consists of different tracks.

A typical itunes playlist looks like below.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
   <dict>
         <dict>
               <dict>
                  <key>Track ID</key>
                  <integer>1769</integer>
                  <key>Name</key>
                  <string>song_1</string>
                  <key>Kind</key>
                  <string>MPEG audio file</string>
                  <key>Total Time</key>
                  <integer>358870</integer>
                  <key>Location</key>
                  <string>/Users/rakesh/Music/iTunes/iTunes%20Media/Music/track1769.mp3</string>
                </dict>
               <dict>
                  <key>Track ID</key>
                  <integer>2413</integer>
                  <key>Name</key>
                  <string>song_2</string>
                  <key>Kind</key>
                  <string>MPEG audio file</string>
                  <key>Total Time</key>
                  <integer>358870</integer>
                  <key>Location</key>
                  <string>/Users/rakesh/Music/iTunes/iTunes%20Media/Music/track2413.mp3</string>
                </dict>

           </dict>

    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>Name</key><string>Library</string>
            <key>Playlist ID</key><integer>4053</integer>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>Track ID</key><integer>2413</integer>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>Track ID</key><integer>1769</integer>
                </dict>
            </array>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>Name</key><string>Movies</string>
            <key>Playlist ID</key><integer>6536</integer>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>Name</key><string>TV Shows</string>
            <key>Playlist ID</key><integer>6539</integer>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>Name</key><string>iTunes U</string>
            <key>Playlist ID</key><integer>5331</integer>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>Name</key><string>Books</string>
            <key>Playlist ID</key><integer>6542</integer>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>Name</key><string>Genius</string>
            <key>Playlist ID</key><integer>6551</integer>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>Name</key><string>On-The-Go 1</string>
            <key>Playlist ID</key><integer>6568</integer>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>Track ID</key><integer>2877</integer>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>Track ID</key><integer>2345</integer>
                </dict>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

Now I have written XSL stylesheet to get detail information of all tracks of given playlists. But the problem is, Under playlists tracks can be in random order and under track informations Ids are stored in sorted manner. When I use Xpath expressions I don't get informations in the same order as mentioned in playlists.

Here's my  XSL.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
  <xsl:output method="text" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="myplaylist" select="'4053'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="playlist_tracks" select="/plist/dict/array/dict[integer[preceding-sibling::key[1]='Playlist ID']=$myplaylist]/array/dict/integer[preceding-sibling::key[1]='Track ID']" />
    <xsl:variable name="tracks" select="/plist/dict/dict/dict[integer[preceding-sibling::key[1]='Track ID']=$playlist_tracks]" />

<xsl:for-each select="$playlist_tracks">
  <xsl:variable select="." name="current" />
    <xsl:for-each select ="$tracks[integer[preceding-sibling::key[1]='Track ID']=$current]" >
       <xsl:value-of select="integer[preceding-sibling::key[1]='Track ID']"/>
         <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="string[preceding-sibling::key[1]='Name']"/>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="integer[preceding-sibling::key[1]='Total Time']"/>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="string[preceding-sibling::key[1]='Location']"/>
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But wit above XSLT I see only first element of the playlists. Can anybody point out whats the mistake? Any XSLT experts please enlighten me.

With the above XML the output dumps like below:
`<Track ID>,<Track Name>,<duration>,<location>`

As we can see, in `<plist><dict><dict><dict>`, All track information are stored sorted by Track Ids. But Playlists contains tracks which are not sorted. so when I query for track infos into `<plist><dict><dict><dict>` from the track ids which I got from playlists `plist/dict/array/dict/array/dict`, I get sorted information. I want it in the same order as mentioned in playlist.

currently I get only first value.
output:
2413,song_2,358870,/Users/rakesh/Music/iTunes/iTunes%20Media/Music/track2413.mp3

expected:
2413,song_2,358870,/Users/rakesh/Music/iTunes/iTunes%20Media/Music/track2413.mp3
1769,song_1,358870,/Users/rakesh/Music/iTunes/iTunes%20Media/Music/track1769.mp3

Comment: There is no number `6711` in the provided, severely malformed XML. Even after correcting the malformed XML the provided transformation doesn't produce any output. I am downvoting this question with the hope that you could improve it.

Comment: Also, this is a copy of a question you submitted a week ago, offered bounty for and accepted an answer. !

Comment: Hi @Dimitre, Actually its not a copy but edited question. I have accepted it for track informations. But order is still not coming. The number 6711 is hardcoded playlist value which is there in my itunes main xml input file.  Also I have not accepted the bounty thing in previous question. waiting for correct answer.

Comment: You must provide a correct question -- including the XML document (well-formed!!!) and the exact wanted result. Your having done so is the reason why you didn't receive good answers -- how can there be "good answers" to undefined questions? Please, correct your XML, so that it is well-formed and so that when the provided transformation is applied on it, some non-empty result is produced. Also, provide the exact result you actually want to produce. Failing to provide this information makes this not a real question and not a well-defined question.

Comment: @Dimitre, I accept you point. It was not well formed question and sorry you had to spend some unfruitful time for it. There then, I have corrected the XML and asked the question.

Comment: Hmm... @Rakesh Singh, this is better, but the XML is still non-well-formed and you still need to provide the exact wanted result for the XML (when this is made well-formed).

Comment: I still don't get *any* result from your XSLT code: `$playlist_tracks` is empty, because this XPath expression doesn't select any node: `/dict/array/dict[integer]` -- to put it in other words there is no `integer` element that is a child of an `/dict/array/dict`  element. Please, correct your question so that it finally becomes meaningful!!!!

Comment: @Dimitre, I have modified my question. First one is input file and you can use that directly. I want all the information in order as mentioned in playlists not in order it has been kept in "plist/dict/dict/dict". Hope this will give an idea what I want. Thanks and apology mistake from my side.

Comment: @Dimitre, Hope you upvote the question. I have corrected the xml properly. This may help others with similar problems. Thanks.

Comment: Good to know, @Rakesh Singh, that you improved the question -- I have reversed my downvote now. I hope that you'll pay more attention in posting meaningful, reproducible, well-formed, non-nonsense questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a problem with qt not liking the iterating of nested variables, here is a reworked version

```
<xsl:template match="/"> 
  <xsl:variable name="myplaylist" select="'4053'"/> 
  <xsl:variable name="playlist_tracks" select="/plist/dict/array/dict[integer[preceding-sibling::key[1]='Playlist ID']=$myplaylist]/array/dict/integer[preceding-sibling::key[1]='Track ID']" /> 
  <xsl:for-each select="$playlist_tracks"> 
    <xsl:variable select="." name="current" /> 
      <xsl:for-each select ="/plist/dict/dict/dict[integer[preceding-sibling::key[1]='Track ID']=$current]" > 
        <xsl:value-of select="integer[preceding-sibling::key[1]='Track ID']"/> 
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text> 
        <xsl:value-of select="string[preceding-sibling::key[1]='Name']"/> 
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text> 
        <xsl:value-of select="integer[preceding-sibling::key[1]='Total Time']"/> 
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text> 
        <xsl:value-of select="string[preceding-sibling::key[1]='Location']"/> 
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text> 
      </xsl:for-each> 
    </xsl:for-each> 
  </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks @Bob Vale, You nailed the problem perfectly well. Its perfectly working well for me. Respect.